# get bitmap from bitmapdescriptor

Tags: android, google-maps

Is it possible to get a Bitmap from [BitmapDescriptor](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptor.html)?

I'm trying to use googles api's to make my app more seemless but I could make custom Marker option objects instead... I would think that BitmapDescriptor would extend FileDescriptor but I don't see that.

Answer (score -1):

All the BitmapDescriptors come from the BitmapDescriptorFactory.

Example custom marker from imageId in MediaStore.

```
final BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmOptions.inSampleSize = 8;  //about the size of standard marker

Bitmap bm = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                            context.getContentResolver(), newImageId,
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
                            bmOptions);
                    if (bm != null) {
                        BitmapDescriptor bd = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromBitmap(bm);
                        if (bd != null) {
                            markeroptions.icon(bd);
```

Comment: You can't cast from filedescriptor to bitmapdescirptor.  This is how you get a bitmap descriptor from a thumbnail image in the media store (just an itermediate step to actually get a correctly sized bitmap to show on a google map.  If you wanted to show the bitmap in a file you have to load it into a bitmap then size it and then still use the bitmapFactory to get a bit map descriptor then change the icon for a marker to and add the marker to the map.

Comment: When I answered you had to use the bitmapfactory to add a custom image to a marker.  Maybe it's changed haven't done much android lately.